# To extract unique value and count from the dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I need to extract the unique value, their counts in the column of a data frame and separate index key column in a data frame.

let us consider following as the example, data frame df1 consists

```
+------+--------+
| city |  score |
+------+--------+
| a    |     12 |
| b    |     45 |
| c    |     50 |
| d    |     65 |
| a    |     58 |
| a    |     70 |
+------+--------+
```

I need output in another data frame df2 as

```
+-------------+--------+--------------+
| unique city |  count |    index key |
+-------------+--------+--------------+
| a           |      3 |            1 |
| b           |      1 |            2 |
| c           |      1 |            3 |
| d           |      1 |            4 |
+-------------+--------+--------------+
```

I am new to pandas I couldn't figure out the way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you need `reset_index` at the first so we can include the index value in the `agg` part

```
df.reset_index().groupby('city').agg({'score':'count','index':'first'})
Out[404]: 
      index  score
city              
a         0      3
b         1      1
c         2      1
d         3      1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
f, u = pd.factorize(df.city)
pd.DataFrame({
    'unique city': u,
    'Count': np.bincount(f),
    'index key': np.arange(len(u)) + 1
}, columns=['unique city', 'Count', 'index key'])

  unique city  Count  index key
0           a      3          1
1           b      1          2
2           c      1          3
3           d      1          4
```